# meta-analysis of survival rates from different studies

Tags: survival, meta-analysis, clinical-trials

Suppose there are $K$ studies (with IPD). For a certain time $t$, we have estimated survival rates $\hat{S}_1(t)$, $\ldots$, $\hat{S}_K(t)$.
I want to pool those estimated survival rates in a meta-analysis (using a survival rate $\hat{S}(t)$ to represent $K$ survival rates)?
Could someone give me some ideas?

Comment: Please explain what is survival and howdo we  compute survi val rates?

Answer (score 1):

Several approaches exist for pooling survival rates from individual patient data (IPD) across multiple studies in a meta-analysis. The approach you use is determined by the type of data, the degree of heterogeneity among studies, and your specific research goals. Here are some general strategies:

**Models with Fixed and/or Random Effects**

- Fixed Effects Model: A fixed effects model can be used if you presume that the genuine effect (survival rate) is the same in all trials. This model implies that reported effect variations are due to random error within studies.
- A model with random effects model (a mixed effects model) is more suited if you believe that the genuine effect may vary between studies. This model takes into account variation both within and between studies.

2. Pooled Kaplan-Meier Curves

- Pooled Kaplan-Meier curves can be generated for time-to-event data. This entails aggregating IPD from all studies and then estimating the survival function for the aggregated data.

**3. A Two-Step Approach:**

- Stage 1: Analyse each trial separately to estimate the survival rate ( ) S k (t) for each study at time t.
- Stage 2: Use meta-analytic techniques to combine these estimates (either fixed or random effects models).

**4. Hierarchical models**

- To account for the fact that patients are nested inside trials, hierarchical (or multi-level) models might be utilised. These models are similar to random effects and mixed effects models and can estimate average survival rates as well as study-specific survival rates.

**5. Study Size or Precision Weighting**

- Consider weighting each study's survival rate by its size (number of participants) or precision (inverse of the variance of the survival rate estimate) when pooling the estimates.

**6. Handling Heterogeneity**

- Analyse study heterogeneity using statistical tests (such as the Cochran's Q test) and metrics (such as the I2 statistic).
- If there is significant variability, it is critical to understand its sources (e.g., differences in study populations, interventions, or results).
- These analyses can be carried out using most statistical software tools such as R (packages such as meta, survival, and metafor), STATA and SAS.

**Practical Procedures**

- Extraction of Data: Collect the survival rates 1 ( ),..., ( ) S 1 (t),...,S K (t) and their variations from each trial.
- Select a Model: Based on heterogeneity, choose between fixed and random effects models.
- Meta-Analysis: Pool the survival rates using the chosen model. Determine the pooled survival rate ( ) S(t) and its confidence interval.
- Sensitivity Analysis: Use sensitivity analyses to determine the robustness of your findings.

**Reporting**

- Report the approach used in detail, including how heterogeneity was handled and any sensitivity analyses.
- Consider utilising forest plots to illustrate the data visually.
- The methodology and assumptions utilised in meta-analysis of survival data must be carefully considered. To confirm the suitability of the chosen method and the validity of the conclusions, it is a good idea that you consult with a statistician who is knowledgeable in survival analysis and meta-analytic techniques.